# call local variable within loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, local

So, what I'm trying to do is to get every unique value of the category 'Nombre Capitulo' of my dataframe, for every 'Nombre Partida' ('Nombre Capitulo' is a subcategory of 'Nombre Partida'). My approach was to create local dataframes for every 'Nombre Partida' and then extract unique values of 'Nombre Capitulo' for every one of them.
So, my question is twofold: 
1. Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?
2. If not, how do I call my recently created local variables? I tried this, but isn't working:

```
Partidas=data1_anio['Nombre Partida'].unique()
for p in Partidas:

    locals()['%s' % p]=data1_anio.loc[data1_anio['Nombre Partida']==p]

    globals()['cap_%s' % p]= ['%s' % p]['Nombre Capitulo'].unique()
```

Local variables are working, but calling them throws:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance, and sorry for the spanish names in the variables, hope it's understandable,
Juan

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use dynamically generated variables. Certainly that is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe you can leverage `groupby` here. It's hard to test without seeing example data, but I think this should do it:

```
data1_anio.groupby('Nombre Partida')['Nombre Capitulo'].unique()
```

**Example:**

```
data1_anio = pd.DataFrame({'Nombre Partida':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                           'Nombre Capitulo':['random1', 'random1', 'random2',
                                              'random3', 'random4', 'random4']})

>>> data1_anio
   Nombre Partida Nombre Capitulo
0              a         random1
1              a         random1
2              a         random2
3              b         random3
4              b         random4
5              b         random4
```

Running the `groupby` returns a Series of all unique values of `Nombre Capitulo` for each `Nombre Partida`:

```
>>> data1_anio.groupby('Nombre Partida')['Nombre Capitulo'].unique()
Nombre Partida
a    [random1, random2]
b    [random3, random4]
```

Comment: You're welcome! `pandas` has a ton of different methods built-in for most dataframe operations.